# prove that the sum of the elements in two subsets is the same

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory, contest-math

> Eight consecutive positive integers are partitioned into two subsets such that the sum of the squares in each subset is the same. Prove that the sum of the elements in each subset is also the same, **assuming** that the smallest element is at least 56.

The method below is mostly a brute force approach.

> Is there a better method than brute force?

For a set $S, $ let $f(S)$ denote the sum of the squares of its elements and let $g(S)$ denote the sum of the elements of S.

Let the integers be $x + 1,\cdots, x + 8$. The sum of the squares in each subset must be $\frac{1}2 \sum_{i=1}^8 (x+i)^2 = \frac{1}2 (8x^2 + 72x + 204) = 4x^2 + 36x+102.$

First we need to show that the partitions must in fact have the same number of elements. If one partition has more than $4$ elements, then its sum of squares will be at least $(x+1)^2 + (x+2)^2 + (x+3)^2 + (x+4)^2 + (x+5)^2 = 5x^2 + 30x + 55,$ which is too large (for $x\ge 11,$ since we would have $x^2 - 6x - 47 > 0$). So no subset can have more than 4 elements, implying than both subsets must have exactly 4 elements.

One of the subsets, say $S_1$, must contain $x+8$, and so the sum of squares of the remaining three elements in this case must be $3x^2 + 20 x +38.$ Let $S_2$ be the other subset. Suppose this subset also contains $x+7$. Then the remaining two elements have a sum of squares equal to $2x^2 + 6x -11.$ The minimum possible sum of squares of two elements is $(x+1)^2 + (x+2)^2 = 2x^2 + 6x + 5$, so we cannot have $x+7$ in $S_1$. If $x+6$ is in $S_1$, then  $f(S_1\backslash \{x+8, x+6\}) = 2x^2 +8x+2$. The only two possible remaining elements are $x+1$ and $x+2$, as $(x+1)^2 + (x+3)^2 > 2x^2 + 8x+2$, and is the second smallest sum of squares of elements. But then $f(S_1) < 2X^2 + 8x+2$, a contradiction.

So suppose $x+5\in S_1$. $f(S_1\backslash \{x+8,x+5\} ) = 2x^2 + 10x + 13,$ and in this case one can verify that $S_1 = \{x+8, x+5, x+2, x+3\}$, since all other choices of two remaining elements give either a smaller or larger sum of squares than $2x^2 + 10x+13$. In this case, $g(S_1) = 4x+18$, so $g(S_1) = g(S_2)$.

We know $x+7$ and $x+6$ are in $S_2 $. So we need to find the remaining two elements of $S_2$. If $x+5$ is in $S_2$, then the square of the remaining element in $S_2$ must be $ 4x^2 + 36x + 102 - ((x+7)^2 + (x+6)^2 + (x+5)^2) = x^2 - 8,$ which is clearly impossible.

So the only possibility is $S_1 = \{x+8, x+5, x+2, x+3\}$.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @markvs I've clarified the question above.

Comment: You say a set of consecutive numbers is partitioned into two subsets whose sums are the same and then ask us to prove that the sums of the subsets are also the same. What does that mean? What.are the second two subsets?

Comment: @JohnDouma perhaps you're misreading the question? I want to prove that if the sum of the squares is the same then the sum of the elements is the same. There are two subsets in the partition.

Comment: @user3472: The OP seems to contain an answer to the Q.

Comment: Do the partition sets have to have the same number of elements ($4$ elements each)? Because if not, I don't think the result holds in general.

Comment: @markvs I did provide an answer, but my answer is pretty much a brute force bash. My question asks if there's an easier approach that can be generalized.

Comment: The OP still does not have a question. Since you do not define "generalization", your explanation does not make sense.

Comment: Very closely related: https://www.intlpress.com/site/pub/files/_fulltext/journals/joc/2016/0007/0001/JOC-2016-0007-0001-a005.pdf

Comment: @EthanBolker: It is well known indeed, but is not related to this problem at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a simple proof if the smallest number, name it $a$, is greater than $56$. We have $$(a+a_1)^2+...+(a+a_4)^2=(a+a_5)^2+...+(a+a_8)^2,$$ where $a_1,...a_8\in \{0,...,7\}$. Hence $$2a(S_1-S_2)=a_5^2+...a_8^2-a_4^2-...-a_1^2,$$ where $S_1=a_1+...+a_4, S_2=a_5+...+a_8$. So $$|S_1-S_2|< (7^2+6^2+5^2+4^2-3^2-2^2-1)/112=1,$$ thus $S_1=S_2$, the two sums are equal, and the two sums of the $a+a_i$ are equal as well.

Comment: This is nice! I've edited it to make it more readable.  Note though this only works for the case where the two subsets have the same size.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a counterexample, if the two partition sets don't have to have the same number of elements, using $\{2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$:

$2^2+3^2+4^2+7^2+8^2=142=5^2+6^2+9^2$.

But $2+3+4+7+8=24$ and $5+6+9=20$.

Comment: That is a valid counterexample. The OP probably assumes that each part contains $4$ numbers, but it is not in the question.

Comment: Actually as I read the original post, there is a section: "First we need to show that the partitions must in fact have the same number of elements..."

Comment: The proof of that statement in the OP is hence wrong. It is easy to find a mistake there. +1

Comment: @user3472: The statement "the partitions must in fact have the same number of elements..." is wrong. The "proof" of it in the OP is also wrong.

Comment: @markvs can you elaborate? If one subset has less than 4 elements, than the other has more than 4 elements, and so the two sums of squares can't possibly be equal. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: @user3472: You claim in the OP that $4x^2 + 36x+102$ is always smaller than $5x^2 + 30x + 55$. Try $x=0$.

Comment: @user3472: Perhaps you should look at this counterexample first.
$2^2+3^2+4^2+7^2+8^2=142=5^2+6^2+9^2$ but $2+3+4+7+8=24$ and $5+6+9=20$.

Comment: @markvs Recall that we were required to assume that the smallest element was >= 56.  This example violates that assumption, and is therefore NOT a valid counterexample.

Comment: @JohnR.Strohm That assumption was added after the counterexample was posted.